# How to run or adjust Windows application efficiently in any screen resolution in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution

How to run or adjust Windows application efficiently in any screen resolution in C# 4.0?

I have done it in 1600 x 1200 resolution but if I try in lower resolutions only some part of the forms are visible.

How to solve this problem? I have searched a lot and got to know about Anchor & Dock will be useful but also to came to know that these should be used from the beginning of designing but I have completed my application while this resolution is now causing the problem when I install the application in any system

Comment: You might want to use WPF in case of wild scaling of anything here and there.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty method of making sure your controls remain visible would be to place a `Panel` on the form, set `Dock = Fill` and `AutoScroll = True`, then place every other control in your form inside it. Your controls won't get cut off, but your program won't win any awards for asthetics. If the program is brand new, that's really not the way you want to start things off.

You could redesign it to make use of Anchors and Docking, as you mentioned. You could also place items such as a row of `Button` controls or a series of `TextBox` controls in a `FlowLayoutPanel`, which will take care of repositioning them as you resize the form.

But if adjusting for screen resolutions is important to you, a better way would have been to use `WPF` from the start. Controls are automatically resized and repositioned as needed, based on their container control.

Answer (score 1):

The real question should be:

- How do I want the controls to resize themselves with their parent?

The answer is that you need to specify anchors. Anchors are used to tell your controls how they should react on resize, and what the concerns should be.

Lets say you have a form with two `[Cancel]` and `[OK]` buttons. They are usually seen fit at the bottom right of your window. But the default `Anchor` property is set to `Top, Left`, so on your form's resize, they stick to the `Top, Left` corner where they belong according to the default settings. This won't be any trouble if your maximize your form, thus you'll have your button probably in the middle of the screen. But at least, you will see every controls adequately.

But what if resize your form smaller and smaller? Do you still want them to stick at the `Top, Left`, or `Bottom, Right` would be more useful? My guess is that you should set the `Anchor` property to `Bottom, Right`, for those two.

This might come in handy to have different `Anchor` property settings depending on how you want your control to react to your form resize. Let's take three `TextBox` controls aligned horizontally with each other. Perhaps your longer field will be your object `Description` property located on horizontal-center of your form. Then, when you risize, you have to think what would make more sense on resize. If it is to make it longer on resize in order to fill your form width with all your control, then perhaps you want the `DescriptionTextBox` to get wider and wider, and the contraray should also be true, on form's resize, you probably want this field to be resized smaller too. Then, to make this happen, you have to set the `Anchor` property to `Left, Right`, so that the edge of your `DescriptionTextBox` control remains at the same very distance of your form's edge at any time.

Another thing is of concern in case of resizing to smaller window, is its `MinimumSize` property. One shall agree that there is use to have a form of size 34x34 pixels. So, setting your `MinimumSize` property to a certain size which makes sens for the form to exist, you will avoid display glitches of controls getting one over another.

For more details on the `Anchor` property: [Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For more details on the `MinimumSize` property: [Control.MinimumSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.minimumsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)